# What standard surface is $\mathbb S^2\#T$ and $\mathbb S^2\#\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to

Tags: general-topology

I want to find out what standard surface $\mathbb S^2\#T$ and $\mathbb S^2\#\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to.

So I started with $\mathbb S^2\#T$. $\mathbb S^2$ has the polygonal presentation (pp.) $<a,b|abb^{-1}a^{-1}>$ and $T$ the presentation $<a,b|aba^{-1}b^{-1}>$. So if I glue the b-sides I get $<a,b|ab(ab)^{-1}a^{-1}>$. I rename the side $(ab)^{-1}$ to $b^{-1}$. So we get $<a,b|abb^{-1}a^{-1}>$. This is the pp. of a sphere so $\mathbb S^2\#T$ is homeomorhic to a sphere.

Now $\mathbb S^2\#\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$. $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ has pp. $<a,b|abab>$. So I glue the first $b^{-1}$ in $\mathbb S^2$ to the first b in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$. I then get $<a,b|ab(ab)aa^{-1}>$ which is the Klein bottle?

Im not sure if I have done this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. Let's figure out what $M \#S^2$ is for any closed surface $M$.

When you do the connect sum, first you remove the interior of a $2$-disk from each surface. So, do this to $M$ and do this to $S^2$. Then we're going to glue the results along their new boundary circles $S^1$. But notice that after removing the interior of a $2$-disk from $S^2$, we've obtained a space whose homeomorphism type we know; it's a (closed) 2-disk!

So if we are going to glue this closed 2-disk into $M \smallsetminus \text{Int}D^2$, what will we end up with?

Comment: Is it $\bar D^2$?

Comment: Not quite. If a disk gets removed from $M$ and then a disk is to be glued into $M \smallsetminus \text{disk}$, the result should be what we started with, which is $M$.

Comment: So $M\#\mathbb S^2$ is homeomorphic to $M$? @kamills

Comment: Exactly. Connect sum with a sphere corresponds to doing nothing at all. (So then you can take $M = T$ and $M = \mathbb{R}P^2$ for your case)

Comment: Which means $\mathbb S^2\#T$ is $T$ and $\mathbb S^2 \# \mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ is the projective plane?